# Scrollable Div with Sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make something where I have a div that scrolls. Inside the div there are "title" elements and as I scroll I want the title element of that section to stick to the top of the div and remain there like a header.

Sort of like what people see on webpages where the menu sticks to the stop of a page as you scroll. This example can clearly be seen on the Mac OS X calendar in the "Day" view.

I think I can deal with the making the element stick part, I saw an interesting solution that I think I can adapt. However I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to know if a title element has reached the top of a scrollable div.

The use case is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="floatLeft">
        <div class="scrollingDiv" style="height:100px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <div>Content</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <div>Content</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="floatRight"></div>
</div>
```

How would I know when the second "Title" has hit the top of my "scrollingDiv", not the top of the page itself?

Thanks!

Comment: It's better if you can create jsfiddle for your Question.

Comment: @Sandeeproop - Or actually make an attempt towards solving it and come back with a more specific problem rather than us doing homework. Check this out ackerchez: http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: thanks for the plugin.....and the hazing :)

Comment: on problem with that pluging is the same as all the others. It goes based off the page top and not a containing div top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an element sticky by setting it's `top` property to zero and making setting `position:absolute;` via css.

```
.stickyTop {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

This will ensure the element stays at the top of the page always.

To identify if an element has reached the top of window you can use `offset()` to identify the current position and check if it's neared the top.

```
$('div.scrollingDiv').scroll(function() {
    var active = null;
    $('.scrollingDiv h4').each(function(idx, val) {
        var topOffset = $(val).offset().top;
        if (topOffset < 20) // elem is 20 px from top
        {
            // Element nearest the top
            active = $(val);
        }

        console.log(active); // Element closest to the top
    });

});
```

The above simply loops though all the `h4` properties searching for the element closest to the top of the page, and logs it.

You can combine these together to create something like a [Funky jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sB24/1/).